# Enter UK as a tourist before ancestry visa starts

Tags: visas, uk

I've just been approved for a UK ancestry visa from Australia. But I've just realised the start date is three days after I'd like to arrive in the UK. Can I enter early, enter as a tourist and then re-enter later on the ancestry visa?

Comment: `enter as a tourist and then re-enter ` Rather than going through the rigmarole, why not enter only once with the Ancestry visa  ?

Comment: @DumbCoder because they cant enter on there visa before it starts. they would need to leave the uk(not to Ireland) and come back. They'd also need to prove they are a visitor on their first entry. If they are denied as a visitor it could cancel their visa.

Comment: @DumbCoder because they cant use the visa before it starts, check this thread out from someone who's done it before http://www.expatforum.com/expats/britain-expat-forum-expats-living-uk/202425-enter-uk-prior-start-uk-ancestry-visa-valid-date.html

Comment: @BritishSam You probably need to read carefully what I wrote. I asked him(her) to enter once with their Ancestry visa.

Comment: @DumbCoder fair enough, that would be ideal, depends if they've already paid a lot for the flight and whether they can change it easily

Answer (score 1):

If you're eligible for a tourist visa, yes.  However, you'll want to be very clear and upfront, especially if your ancestral visa is in your passport, as [attempting to enter earlier than the date specified *may* cause your visa to be cancelled](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57288/entry-for-tourist-with-student-visa).

I'd recommend having your channel-hopping tickets printed out, evidence of accommodation and make it very clear that you will definitely be leaving before your ancestral visa is due to start, and returning then.