# Can I enter the UK on a tourist Visa while my Ancestry Visa application is still pending?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm just about to finish my application for an Ancestry Visa to the UK. I have a trip planned there with my bf's parents in a few weeks and I'm worried my visa won't be approved in time for me to get there. I'm wondering:

a) If I can enter the UK on a tourist visa before while my ancestry visa is pending and then re-enter the country on that visa.
b) Do I have to go back to Australia to actually collect my visa/30 day entrance pass once it is approved, or is it just my passport that I need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enter UK as a tourist before ancestry visa starts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116639/enter-uk-as-a-tourist-before-ancestry-visa-starts)

Comment: Not a duplicate. There is a significant difference between entering while an ancestry visa is processing, and trying to enter with it granted but before it starts.